# Function & object prototype

Tags: javascript, object, oop, constructor

in this question Person has constructor function and pesron1 has instance or object that created by Person.
hi guys, why this code return false Person.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(Person) and why
this code has true Person.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(person1)?

should return true!!

Comment: Person is a function, but an instance of Person is ... well ... an instance of Person

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a misunderstanding in your code. Let's break down each statement and see what's happening:

1. `Person.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(Person)`:

This statement is comparing `Person.prototype` to the prototype of the `Person` function itself. In other words, you are comparing the prototype property of the constructor function `Person` to the prototype of `Person`. Since both `Person.prototype` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(Person)` point to the same object (which is the prototype object for instances created with `new Person()`), this statement should return `true`.

2. `Person.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(person1)`:

This statement is comparing `Person.prototype` to the prototype of an object `person1` created using the `Person` constructor. Assuming that `person1` is created properly with `new Person()`, this statement should also return `true` because `person1` inherits from `Person.prototype`.

Here's a simple example to illustrate this:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const person1 = new Person("John");

console.log(Person.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(Person)); // Should return true
console.log(Person.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(person1)); // Should return true
```

If your code is returning `false` for the first statement, there might be something unusual or incorrect happening elsewhere in your code. Make sure you are using the `new` keyword when creating instances of `Person`, and ensure that there are no other modifications or assignments to `Person.prototype` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(Person)` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: "*Since both Person.prototype and Object.getPrototypeOf(Person) point to the same object*" they don't, though. Never have, never will. "*If your code is returning false for the first statement, there might be something unusual or incorrect happening elsewhere in your code.*" `false` is exactly the correct result from that expression. The `prototype` property of the constructor and the prototype of the constructor aren't the same thing.